# How does MS edge know which pdf page position one is?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

Let's say you open a pdf, from your local system or web. It opens itself scrolled a little up. How do I do it?

I searched the web but couldn't find the solution. Someone who has touched this type of problem and could give more info about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to a position in a PDF via a browser link in Edge you need  to add the "Open With" fragment `#zoom=###,###,###` so for the way to scroll down 100 (at 150% scale you will need `#zoom=150,0,100`. The zoom does not affect the amount of scroll so at 100 and 150 zoom it will end with the same amount.

In this example whatever the zoom the start without margin is 130.

[image]

[image]

https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/lua/Research-proposal.pdf#zoom=150,75,130

[image]

For other options see https://pdfobject.com/pdf/pdf_open_parameters_acro8.pdf#page=5

Comment: This answer is useful!